# ReactJS: Which method is best to store parameters of a HTML canvas element, referenced through useRef?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, data-structures, html5-canvas

I'm creating a react app that involves drawing on a HTML canvas element, defined like so:

```
function TestElement(props) {
  const canvas = useRef(null);

  return (
    <canvas className='visualizer' ref={canvas} />
  );
}
```

In order to access things like the canvas height or width when drawing, I set some `vars` in a `useEffect` hook:

```
var center_x;
var center_y;
// etc...

useEffect( () => {
  if (canvas != null) {
    center_x = canvas.current.width / 2;
    center_y = canvas.current.height / 2;
    // etc...
  }
}, [canvas]);
```

However, eslint gives the following warning:

> Assignments to the 'center_x' variable from inside React Hook useEffect will be lost after each render. To preserve the value over time, store it in a useRef Hook and keep the mutable value in the '.current' property. Otherwise, you can move this variable directly inside useEffect.eslintreact-hooks/exhaustive-deps

However, shouldn't this value not be retained between renders? Because it's possible that between renders the size/shape of the canvas changes resulting in a it having to be reset? I'm at a crossroads where I can use multiple methods to store these values:

- vars
- useState
- useRef

but I'm not sure which to use. And because performance is important, I don't want to pick one that could result in unneeded overhead and performance hits. **Which one of these three methods should I use to store the parameters of the canvas for best performance and behavior (frequently drawing to canvas)?** Should I listen to eslint, or is using vars fine?

I'm a bit new to react so I would appreciate any guidance. Thanks.

Comment: To access a node(canvas node) you shoud use `canvas.current`,aslo add to `useEffect` deps [canvas.current, canvas.height, canvas.width], and use `useState` to prevent many re-renders

Comment: @LevayaPochta ah my bad, that was a typo, meant to write `canvas.current` thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting `canvas.current` in the dependency array of your `useEffect()` is an anti-pattern and you will get a warning about it:

> Mutable values like 'canvas.current' aren't valid dependencies because mutating them doesn't re-render the component.

As [this article](https://medium.com/welldone-software/usecallback-might-be-what-you-meant-by-useref-useeffect-773bc0278ae) by Vitali Zaidman points out, "there is no callback or re-render when a component is (un)mounted and attached to ref.current using useRef".  What you want to use is actually `useCallback()`.  When the latest canvas DOM reference is returned by `useCallback()`, you can react by setting `centerX` and `centerY`.  As you suggested, you can track these variables as state with `useState()`.

```
const [centerX, setCenterX] = useState(null);
const [centerY, setCenterY] = useState(null);

const canvasRef = useCallback((canvasNode) => {
  setCenterX(canvasNode.width / 2);
  setCenterY(canvasNode.height / 2);
}, []);

...

return (<canvas ref={canvasRef} />);
```